# Can three iterations can be done in a single line? Python 3 for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

The following code works fine. But instead of calling player_apps three times can it done in a single statement ?

```
for club in all_clubs:
    total_app = sum(player['season_apps'] for player in players_apps if player['player_club'] == club)
    total_sub_app = sum(player['season_sub_apps'] for player in players_apps if player['player_club'] == club)
    total_goals = sum(player['season_goals'] for player in players_apps if player['player_club'] == club)
    club_app_goal.append({'club' : club, 'total_app' : total_app, 'total_sub_app' : total_sub_app, 'total_goals' : total_goals})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```
for club in all_clubs:
    total_app = np.sum([[player['season_apps'], player['season_sub_apps'], player['season_goals']] for player in players_apps if player['player_club'] == club], axis=1)
    club_app_goal.append({'club' : club, 'total_app' : total_app[0], 'total_sub_app' : total_app[1], 'total_goals' : total_app[2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically yes using `functools.reduce`, but it won't make the code prettier and I'm not sure it will really improve perfs:

```
total_app, total_sub_app, total_goals = reduce(
    lambda a, b: tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)), 
    ((p['season_apps'], p['season_sub_apps'], p['season_goals']) for p in players_apps if p["club"] == club), 
    (0, 0, 0)
    )
```

A more interesting "optimization" IMHO would be to filter the players only once per club:

```
for club in all_clubs:
    players = [player for player in players_apps if player['player_club'] == club]
    total_app = sum(player['season_apps'] for player in players)
    total_sub_app = sum(player['season_sub_apps'] for player in players)
    total_goals = sum(player['season_goals'] for player in players)
```

which is much more readable and might even actually be faster (or not, depending on your data).

This being said, you would probably benefit from using either a proper relational database (relational databases have been specifically designed for this kind of computations) or at least Numpy or Panda.